AssertJ: How to know which condition(s) failed when using allOf()
I am using assertj library for performing assertions in my JUnit5 tests.
I want to perform multiple assertions, I was exploring few different ways and got to know about Conditions.
final var condition1 = new Condition<String>(text -> text != null, "Input not null");
final var condition2 = new Condition<String>(text -> text.equalsIgnoreCase("abc"), "Input not matching");
assertThat(someString).satisfies(allOf(condition1, condition2));

When I execute above code, I get below output:
Expecting actual: "PQR"
to satisfy:
all of:[Input not null, Input not matching]

The output doesn't really specify which of the 2 conditions failed.
I can use separate statements to assert each condition or as suggested in this question, I could do something like:
assertThat(input).satisfies(text -> {
    assertThat(text).isNotNull();
    assertThat(text).isEqualTo("abc");
});

There is another way to do it using ThrowingConsumer along with andThen as below -
ThrowingConsumer<String> consumer1 = text -> assertThat(text).isNotBlank();
ThrowingConsumer<String> consumer2 = text -> assertThat(text).isEqualTo("abc");
// usage
assertThat(text).satisfies(consumer1.andThen(consumer2));

But I would like to know how to get exact failure message when using allOf().

We could indeed be more informative about the failing condition, in the meantime the suggested satisfies alternative is a good way to get the error message.
I created https://github.com/assertj/assertj/issues/3537 to track this issue.
Edit: the issue has been resolved, the error message now looks like 

Hi @joel-costigliola - are these changes available to use?

Will be in the next release 3.27.0

https://github.com/assertj/assertj/pull/3554#issuecomment-2267276973
By above merged PR, we can check which condition failed inside of allOf(..)!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
